# smallest and largest in java. else if?

Tags: java, if-statement

i had to make a program that told you the largest and smallest number of 5 numbers and i keep getting smallest = 0 and largest = 0 on output. i havent added comments or anything like that yet, and ive tried else if and it isent working at all(surprised i got else working). Can someone please help me with this one. I shouldn't need help with this but i just cant figure this out.

```
public class int_big_small {
    public static void main(String args[]){

        int num1=3, num2=9, num3=5, num4 = 3, num5 = 7;
        int largest = 0, smallest = 0;

            if(num1 > num2){
                num1 = largest;
                num2 =  smallest;
            }else{
                num2 = largest;
                num1 = smallest;
            }

            if(num3>largest){
                num3 = largest;
            }
            if(num3<smallest)
                num3 = smallest;
            if(num4>largest){
                num4 = largest;
            }
            if(num4<smallest)
                num4 = smallest;

            if(num5>largest){
                    num5 = largest;
                }
                if(num5<smallest)
                    num5 = smallest;



            System.out.println("the smallest number is " + smallest + " and the largest is " + largest);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your assignments are all in reverse order - they should be `smallest = whatever`, not `whatever = smallest`

This is also crying out to be put in for loop.

```
int[] nums = new int[] {num1, num2, num3, num4, num5};
int smallest = nums[0];
int largest = nums[0];
for(int i = 1; i < nums.length; i++) {
    if(nums[i] < smallest) {
        smallest = nums[i];
    }
    if(nums[i] > largest) {
        largest = nums[i];
    }
}
```

Initialize `smallest` and `largest` to a valid int from your list of numbers - initializing them to `0` is going to result in `smallest` equaling `0` when you're finished.  (The only default values that wouldn't cause problems are `smallest = Integer.MAX_VALUE; largest = Integer.MIN_VALUE;`)

Comment: I would use a loop but for some reason i have alot of trouble putting loops into things like this. I have trouble how it would work. Thanks for the help I switched all the largest and numbers. thanks

Comment: What this loop is doing is putting num1, num2, etc in an indexed list of integers, so after `nums = new int[] {num1, num2, ..}`, int[0] == num1, int[1] == num2, and so on up to int[4] == num5.  The index is 0-based, so the first element is at nums[0] and the last is at nums[nums.length - 1].  `smallest` and `largest` are initialized to num[0] so your loop can start at num[1].  The loop goes through the remaining four numbers and compares them to `smallest` and `largest`.

Answer (score 1):

```
public int min(int a, int b) {
    if(a > b) return b;
    return a;
}

public int max(int a, int b) {
    if(a > b) return a;
    return b;
}

int num1=3, num2=9, num3=5, num4 = 3, num5 = 7;
int largest = num1, smallest = num1;

smallest = min(min( min(num1, num2) , min(num3, num4)), num5);
largest  = max(max( max(num1, num2) , max(num3, num4)), num5);
```

Comment: Wouldn't your call to min and max not work since they take in 2 arguments each and you're passing in three? Or am I reading it wrong?

Comment: Initialize `largest` and `smallest` to num1, or else initialize `smallest` to `Integer.MAX_VALUE` and `largest` to `Integer.MIN_VALUE`.  Currently, the code is going to result in `smallest` equaling 0, when it ought to equal 3

Answer (score 1):

If you're *learning* Java, use the solution with the array and loops. If you're *using* Java, it can be done in 3 lines:

```
List<Integer> list = Arrays.asList(num1, num2, num3, num4, num5);
int smallest = Collections.min(list);
int largest  = Collections.max(list);
```